# Can I access the stage dimensions in AS3 before the Stage class is instantiated?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashdevelop

I have a class that relies on the stage width in its constructor. I don't need to construct it when the app first loads, but I still get the 1009 error (attempted access of null object) because the stage hasn't been instantiated yet and I guess when it compiles it checks all constructors to make sure that everything is available at compile time... fine.

I could just use variables to hold that width value and then update that value when the stage changes size, but I'd like a more elegant approach. Is there a way to access the stage properties even before it is instantiated? Or is there another way to do this?

I'm compiling for AIR for desktop using Flex SDK and coding in FlashDevelop.

My obligatory code:

```
public class MouseSenseWindow extends Sprite {
    private var _sensitivity:Number = 1;
    private var _bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
    public function MouseSenseWindow(sense:Number):void{
        sensitivity = sense;
        drawBox();
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseHit);
    }


    private function mouseHit(me:MouseEvent):void {
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseHit);
        grab();
    }


    private function drawBox():void{
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.beginFill( 0, 0 );
        graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth / _sensitivity, stage.stageHeight );
        graphics.endFill();
    }


    public function grab():void{
        startDrag(false, _bounds);
    }


    public function get sensitivity():Number{return _sensitivity;}
    public function set sensitivity(s:Number):void{
        _sensitivity = s;
        drawBox();
    }
} //end class
```

Comment: In case you want to know the reason I want a *more elegant approach* is that I anticipate the window size a) changing at runtime and b) changing before I compile so as to be able to test different screen sizes and I know I'll make a future headache for myself if I have to change the AIR settings *and* a global variable each time I want to test some new size.

Comment: Normally Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE does the thing (and FD adds the routine to capture this moment to the Main class by default). The thing is, Stage is instantiated before any code is executed, however a DisplayObject have no access to the stage unless this DisplayObject is attached to it (directly or through its parent tree).

Comment: @Organis Ah! I see! Thanks for clearing up that confusion! I should be able good from here.